# Entity Framework CTP5 Code First: using non-primitive type as key

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I have a project which has quite a few data-structures, and I want to introduce a database into it. I'm looking into Entity Framework CTP5's code-first feature.

Now, I'm using a distinct Identifier type for each of my types (e.g. TypeAIdentifier, TypeBIdentifier, etc.). It's nice because it allows for type safety when working with these identifiers. The problem is that I can't seem to get EF to use a non-primitive-type as an identifier. There's a hint in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx:

```
KeyAttribute 

KeyAttribute is used to specify that a property/column is part of the primary 
key of the entity and applies to scalar properties only.
```

Indeed, the following program throws an exception:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDb db = new MyDb();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

class MyDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}

class MyObject
{
    [Key] public MyIdentifierType MyId { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
}

class MyIdentifierType
{
    public int UniqueId { get; set; }
}
```

Strangely enough this program throws a MissingMethodException ("no parameterless constructor defined for this object"), but I'm sure this is related to the KeyAttribute because either of the following makes the program run:

1. Remove [Key]; or
2. Move [Key] to IntValue.

How can I get EF to map my Identifier classes as PKs? Two options that come to mind:

1. Figure out a way to get EF to use a non-primitive-type as a PK.
2. Put an 'int' as the PK and get EF to convert this 'int' to MyIdentifier (this has the disadvantage that if I ever decide to use something other than an 'int' I'll have to update both MyIdentifier and the mapping, but it will at least let me preserve the identifier type safety). I thought Function Imports would let me do this, but it seems that are built on top of stored procedures.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I was able to achieve this in FluentNHibernate using CompositeId(x => x.MyId).KeyProperty(x => x.UniqueId). Is there a CompositeId equivalent in EF CTP5? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert the key with a property to the custom type.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    public MyIdentifierType MyId
    {
        get { return new MyIdentifierType {UniqueId = Id}; } 
        set { Id = value.UniqueId; }
    }
}
```